# Missing image in Typo3 $this->contentObj in 6.0.3

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

in TYPO3 6.0.2 I got an Extbase/Fluid-Extension. The function in the Controller looks like this:

```
$this->contentObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
$data = $this->contentObj->data;
print_r($data);
```

This will return a `tt_content` - object including `image => /path/to/image`. Everything fine.

```
[bodytext] => Lorem ipsum dolor 
[image] => ../../fileadmin/user_upload/images/businessman.jpg
```

Today changing source to TYPO3 6.0.3 everything the same but the image is just a `"1"`.

```
[bodytext] => Lorem ipsum dolor
[image] => 1
```

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you get now only the reference counter instead of the filename?  The IMAGE Content Object should be able to handle. But i do not know, how it is in extbase.

Comment: I think you are right. I even don't know myself, so i wrote an SQL-query returning the file reference.

Answer (score 2):

i found this to get files without sql query

```
    public function myAction(){        

    // get data of the content object
    $data = $this->contentObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data;

    // Neu ab Typo3 6.0.3 -> Bild in tt_content-Object wird nicht mehr mit zurueckgeliefert, daher:     
    $fileRepository = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Resource\\FileRepository');
    $fileObjects = $fileRepository->findByRelation('tt_content', 'image', $data['uid']);
    $files = array();
    foreach ($fileObjects as $key => $value) {
      $files[$key]['reference'] = $value->getReferenceProperties();
      $files[$key]['original'] = $value->getOriginalFile()->getProperties();
    } 

    #t3lib_utility_Debug::debug($files);
    #die('Ende');        

    // Files in Fluid ausgeben
    $this->view->assign('files', $files);        

    // Daten in Fluid ausgeben
    $this->view->assign('data', $data);
}
```

fluid

```
                    <f:for each="{files}" as="file">                        
                    <li>
                        <a href="{file.reference.link}"><img src="fileadmin{file.original.identifier}" alt="" /></a>
                        <p class="flex-caption"><f:format.nl2br>{file.reference.description}</f:format.nl2br></p>
                    </li>                        
                </f:for>
```

Answer (score 0):

the bug appears to be a result of the security update where the typical jumpURL system has changed (SQL Injection). I filed a bug here: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/46090

Comment: Thank you. In the bug report Marc wrote: "...number of attached images because the image field is a reference record to the file record since 6.0.". I was wondering why it was working with 6.0.2 but not with 6.0.3 and also 6.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Since TYPO3 6 the method "`function getContentObject($name)`" was located in 
*typo3\sysext\cms\tslib\class.tslib_content.php*.

Content of this file:

```
/*
 * @deprecated since 6.0, the classname tslib_cObj and this file is obsolete
 * and will be removed with 6.2. The class was renamed and is now located at:
 * typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/ContentObjectRenderer.php
 */
require_once \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('frontend') . 'Classes/ContentObject/ContentObjectRenderer.php';
```

But I don't see any differences between the old an the new file containing my problem.

I didn't find out how to get the file reference for the tt_content-entry "native", so I wrote a SQL-query:

```
 public function bla() {
    // get data of the content object
    $this->contentObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
    $data = $this->contentObj->data;
    // Neu ab Typo3 6.0.3 -> Bild in tt_content-Object wird nicht mehr mit zurueckgeliefert, daher: 
    // https://forge.typo3.org/issues/46090
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250351/missing-image-in-typo3-this-contentobj-in-6-0-3
    $res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_query(
        'select sys_file.identifier from sys_file_reference left join sys_file on sys_file_reference.uid_local = sys_file.uid where sys_file_reference.uid_foreign='.$data['uid'].' and sys_file_reference.deleted=0'
    );
    while ($row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $data['image'] = $row['identifier'];
    }
    #print_r($data);
    // assign the data to the fluid template
    $this->view->assign('data', $data);
}
```